# Kendo UI Grid Fires CRUD Operations multiple times

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, crud

I've seen this problem in many places but I can't seem to find a solution. So I have defined a Kendo grid with CRUD operations the thing is that the previous fired operations get fired again. 
    Say you delete entry X and then you add entry Y, the create operation fires and after that the delete operation (for X - which has been deleted) fires again. Same thing if you first create an element and then edit another, it edits the 2nd element and then it re-fires the 1st create statement and inserts a duplicate for the 1st inserted element. If you go on an on with several operations a nightmare happens with all the other previous operations being fired and sent to the controller.

My grid is:

```
 function InitializeIPAddressesGrid(userID) {
    selectedUserID = userID;
    $(".ipAddresses").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: IPAdressesDataSource,
        sortable: {
            mode: "single",
            allowUnsort: false
        }, 
        remove: function (e) {
            this.refresh();
            var canDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
            if (!canDelete) {
             e.preventDefault();
             }

        },
        height: 420,
        resizable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSize: 10
        },
        selectable: "row",
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable:{mode: "inline", confirmation:false} ,
        columns: [{
            field: "IpAddress",
            title: "IP Address"
        },
        {
            field: "Status",
            title: "Status"
        },
        {
            field: "LockedUntil",
            title: "Locked until",
            template: "#=kendo.toString(LockedUntil, 'yyyy/MM/dd' )#" 
        },
           { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "180px" }
        ]
    });

}
var IPAdressesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "json",
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    //scrollable:false, 
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: websiteRootUrl + '/PortalAuthorization/GetIPAddressesList',
        },
        update: {
            url: websiteRootUrl + "/PortalAuthorization/UpdateIP",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST', 
            complete: function (e) {
                            if (e.status != 200) {
                                alert(eval('(' + e.responseText + ')').Message);
                            }
                            }
            },
        create:  {
              url: websiteRootUrl + "/PortalAuthorization/CreateIP",
              dataType: "json",
              type: 'POST',
               complete: function (e) {
                                if (e.status != 200) {
                                    alert(eval('(' + e.responseText + ')').Message);

                                }
                                }
              },
        destroy: {
             url: websiteRootUrl + "/PortalAuthorization/DeleteIP",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'DELETE',
            complete: function (e) {
                            if (e.status != 200) {
                                alert(eval('(' + e.responseText + ')').Message);
                            }
                            }
        },

        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {

            if (operation == "update" && options) {
                return {ipAddress: options.IpAddress , 
                        status: options.Status ,
                        lockedUntil: kendo.toString(options.LockedUntil, 'yyyy/MM/dd' ),
                        pkey: options.ID,
                        databaseID: selectedDatabaseID };
            }
            else
            if (operation == "destroy" && options)
            {
                 return {
                        databaseID: selectedDatabaseID,
                        pkey: options.ID,
                        userIDParam: selectedUserID
                         };   
            }
            else
             if (operation == "create" && options) {
                return {ipAddress: options.IpAddress , 
                        status: options.Status ,
                        lockedUntil: kendo.toString(options.LockedUntil, 'yyyy/MM/dd' ),
                        pkey: options.ID,
                        userIDParam: selectedUserID,
                        databaseID: selectedDatabaseID };
            }
            else
            {
            options.databaseID = selectedDatabaseID;
            options.userID = selectedUserID;
            return options;
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
                 id: "ID",
                 fields: {
                        IpAddress: { type: "string" },
                        Status: { type: "string" },
                        LockedUntil: { type: "date" }
                 }
             },      
        data: function (data) {
            return data.Items;
        },
        total: function (data) {
            return data.TotalCount;
        }
    }
});
```

My controllers are:

```
 public object UpdateIP(int databaseID, long pkey, string status, string lockedUntil, string ipAddress)
    {
          var database = [...];
        DynamicDataRepository repository = [...];
        string query = "...";

           repository.ExecuteNonQuery(query);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public object DeleteIP(int databaseID, long pkey, int? userIDParam)
    {
         var database = [...];
        DynamicDataRepository repository = [...];
        string query = "...";

           repository.ExecuteNonQuery(query);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public object CreateIP(int databaseID, long? pkey, string status, string lockedUntil, string ipAddress, int? userIDParam)
    {
        var database = [...];
        DynamicDataRepository repository = [...];
        string query = "...";

           repository.ExecuteNonQuery(query);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Do you have any ideea? where I've done something wrong? thanks in advance. P.S. the queries in the controllers work fine.

Comment: In case of creation is not enough returning OK, you should return the record with an id different than the default value. For updates, you should return the element as well in order to remove the dirty flag.

Comment: How do I do that? I mean, in case of an update do I have to make another query to get the updated data-row and pass it as a json? - like in READ? also, should I initialize something in the complete event? and what about in the case of Delete?.. The thing is I have another method of creating the grids, which is dynamic.. and worst case scenario I'll redo the grid(s) in question (I have like 4-5 grids done "manually" and another 20 something done dynamically) like that.. but those actions also return OK - the onse used dynamic. only difference is that they are in an api controller.

Comment: @OnaBai: For updates, you don't have to return the element, returning only Id of edited element as response body is enough.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the problem, followed OnaBai's suggestion of returning the Updated/Created entity, and in the case of a Delete I returned the ID of the deleted entry.

```
 public object UpdateIP(int databaseID, long pkey, string status, string lockedUntil, string ipAddress)
    {
        var database = [...];
        DynamicDataRepository repository = [...];
        string query = [...];

        IPList updatedIP = new IPList { ID = pkey, IpAddress = ipAddress, Status = status, LockedUntil = DateTime.Today };

        return Json(updatedIP, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       // return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Only one mention: in the case of a CREATE, the method didn't seem to work so what I did is in the .complete event of the CREATE operation I did a  ipGrid.dataSource.read();
ipGrid.refresh(); - so the operation doesn't repeat itself. ( I read that in this case there might be problem with the model definition - setting the ID field - but I did set that one). Many thanks to OnaBai